# Android: Webview loading URL failed?

Tags: java, android, url, webview, sd-card

I am able to run a code that copies files and folders from one directory to another, I have the ff.input:

Source: new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "E_BU/EngagiaDroid") which gives the output **/mnt/sdcard/E_BU/EngagiaDroid** on my device, AND,
Destination: new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "EngagiaDroid") which gives the output **/mnt/sdcard/EngagiaDroid** on my device.

However, when I used the [webview code in this link](http://codeofaninja.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-view-webpage-inside-your-android.html) to view my html using: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +  "/EngagiaDroid/videos.html" 
which gives the output **/mnt/sdcard/EngagiaDroid/videos.html**, **webview was not able to load that url**. But when I change the url to other url for example
http://codeofaninja.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-view-webpage-inside-your-android.html, it was able to load, meaning the webview code works.

I'm sure that the files were copied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. Have you set `webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);` on the WebView?

Other than that, the most likely thing would be a problem with the URL. It should start with `file:///`, for one thing. Maybe something like:

```
"file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/EngagiaDroid/videos.html"
```

Examples I've seen often come out to `file:///sdcard/...`

Comment: Wow! thanks a lot Sven Viking! All the things you pointed out made it work for me. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
wView.loadUrl("file://sdcard/About_Eng.htm");
```

Use this l
ine and its work

Comment: This may work in some cases, but it's no longer the true path on current devices (just a symlink for backwards computability), so you really should query the device for the proper path (as in the accepted answer) rather than hard coding it.